# Django insert or update in one table should reflect in another table

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a cart using django-carton App. I have two models: Halls and Caterer. I want to add either of these Halls or Caterer object in cart when I will call add() method. While using this API, I need to register my model in settings.py as below

```
CART_PRODUCT_MODEL = 'marriage_halls.models.Hall'
```

I can register only one model at a time. So I can't add Caterer object in the cart.To resolve this issue, I'm planning to create new 'product' model which will contain 3 columns viz. {name, price, city}. These are the columns which are common in both Hall and Caterer and I want to display them when I'll call show() method. My first question is, is it a correct way to do it?

If its  a correct approach, What I want to do is, whenever I will add new Hall or Caterer in their respective tables through Django's admin interface, only these 3 column values should get inserted to Product table (INSERT new row in product table).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make Product a base class and use multi table inheritance.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Comment: So if I make product class a base class and Hall and Caterer as child classes of it, and if I add new record in Hall or Caterer, then will it be  inserted in a product table as well? and can I somehow insert primary keys of Hall and Caterer in Product table as a two different columns viz. HallId, CatererId